# How to map 0/1 as true/false while receiving boolean parameter in web api request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api method like this

```
 [HttpGet, HttpHead]
 [Route("{fileId}")]
 public IActionResult DownloadFirmware(Guid fileId, bool crcMode = false)
```

I want to pass 0 and 1 for `crcMode` and still want to have the parameter type `bool`.

Is there any way to do this? By may be overriding the request parameter parser?

There are other ways if I change the type of the parameter, then it can be achieved but is there any way keeping the type `bool`?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the datatype bool in the method. and can convert this to int.

```
bool tr = true;
bool fl = false;
int x = Convert.ToInt32(tr); //1
int y = Convert.ToInt32(fl); //0
```

You can do revers of this also. like declare the datatype int in the method and cast to bool.

```
int x = 0;
int y = 1;

bool a = Convert.ToBoolean(x); //true
bool b = Convert.ToBoolean(y); //false
```

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that I know all these solutions but I am looking for something that will not make me change the data type of the parameter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could solve your problem:

```
[HttpGet, HttpHead]
[Route("{fileId}")]
public IActionResult DownloadFirmware(Guid fileId, bool crcMode = false)
{
  //do something
}

[HttpGet, HttpHead]
[Route("{fileId}")]
public IActionResult DownloadFirmware(Guid fileId, int crcMode = 0)
{
  return DownLoadFireware(fileId, crcMode != 0)
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that I know all these solutions but I am looking for something that will not make me change the data type of the parameter

Comment: You don't have to change the parameters of the method, you just create a second method with an int parameter that calls the first method